# Website using HTML/CSS/SASS/Bootstrap/JQuery

Tags: beginner, jquery, html, css, sass

I'm learning Sass and responsive websites, I've made this simple portfolio website with the help of a bootstrap template (freelancer) and I'd like to know if I'm doing SASS correctly and ways to improve my website code. Also is my project structure correct as a standard? Thanks in advance!

index.html

```
<body id="page--top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar__button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavCollapse">Menú</button>
                <a class="navbar-brand navbar__brand" href="#page--top">Evan</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar__collapsingNav" id="mainNavCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page--top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#portfolio" class="navbar__item">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about" class="navbar__item">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact" class="navbar__item">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="container header" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img class="img-responsive header__profileimage" src="assets/img/profile.jpg" alt="myPhoto">
                    <div class="header__textbox">
                        <h1 class="header__textbox--title">EVAN SURNAME</h1>
                        <h4 class="header__textbox--subtitle">Web Developer</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Portfolio Section1 -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="section1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="section1__title">Portfolio</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image" alt="Project1">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image" alt="Project2">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image" alt="Project3">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image" alt="Project4">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image" alt="Project5">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 section1__item">
                    <a href="#" class="section1__item--link">
                        <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png" class="img-responsive section1__image--last" alt="Project6">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section2 -->
    <section class="section2" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="section2__title">About</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p class="section2__text">Freelancer is a free bootstrap theme created by Start Bootstrap. The download includes the complete source files including HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as well as optional LESS stylesheets for easy customization.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="section2__text">Whether you're a student looking to showcase your work, a professional looking to attract clients, or a graphic artist looking to share your projects, this template is the perfect starting point!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section3 -->
    <section id="contact" class="section3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="section3__title">Contact Me</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control section3__form--input" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control section3__form--input" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control section3__form--input" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control section3__form--input" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg section3__button">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer--above">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3 class="footer--above__title">Location</h3>
                        <p class="footer--above__text">3481 Melrose Place
                            <br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <iframe class="footer--above__map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d183615.334415116!2d1.2244688902059417!3d44.02160942347321!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12ac0de6de9463e9%3A0xc7fb153793253908!2sMontauban%2C+France!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sie!4v1490815128696" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                    </div>

                    <div class="footer-col col-md-4">
                        <h3 class="footer--above__title">Social Media</h3>
                        <ul class="footer--above__list">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--fb"></span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--tw"></span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--lkin"></span></a>
                                <a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--ghub"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer--below">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p class="footer--below__text">Copyright &copy; Evan 2017</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

sass

```
/* FONT FAMILY AND SIZE */

$text__family--sans: "Lucida Sans Unicode",
"Lucida Grande",
sans-serif !default;
$text__size--base: 15px !default;
$text__size--xbig: 70px !default;
$text__size--big: 50px !default;
$text__size--md: 35px !default;
$text__size--lowmd: 25px !default;
$text__size--sm: 17px !default;
$text__size--xsm: 13px !default;

/* TEXT COLORS */

$text__color--white: #FFFFFF !default;
$text__color--black: #000000 !default;
$text__color--base: #333333 !default;
$text__color__secondary--light: #ffc03d !default;
$text__color__secondary: #e09f16 !default;

/* BACKGROUND COLORS  */

$background__color--navbar: #990000 !default;
$background__color--footer--above: #e81e1e !default;
$background__color--secondary: #e09f16 !default;
$background__color--white: #FFFFFF !default;

/* LAYOUT */

$padding--xbig: 100px !default;
$padding--big: 60px !default;
$padding--sm: 30px !default;
$padding--xsm: 15px !default;

/* ICONS */

$bars-icon: "\f0c9";
$facebook-icon: "\f09a";
$twitter-icon: "\f099";
$linkedin-icon: "\f0e1";
$github-icon: "\f09b";

/* ------ MIXINS ------ */

@mixin text($size, $family: $text__family--sans, $color: $text__color--base, $align: center, $line: normal, $weight: normal) {
    font-size: $size;
    font-family: $family;
    color: $color;
    text-align: $align;
    line-height: $line;
    font-weight: $weight;
}

@mixin img($height: auto, $width: auto, $border: auto, $radius: 0, $shadow: 0, $display: block) {
    height: $height;
    width: $width;
    border: $border;
    border-radius: $radius;
    box-shadow: $shadow;
    display: $display;
}

@mixin layout($padding: auto, $margin: 0 auto, $minheight: auto) {
    padding: $padding;
    min-height: $minheight;
    margin: $margin;
}

@mixin icon($icon, $color: $background__color--white) {
    content: $icon;
    color: $color;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


/* ------------------- STYLES ------------------- */

body {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

p {
    @include text($size: $text__size--base, $color: $text__color--base);
}


/* NAVBAR */

.navbar {
    background: $background__color--navbar;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    @include layout($padding: 10px);
    .navbar__button {
        @include text($size: $text__size--md, $color: $text__color--white);
        background: $background__color--secondary;
        border: 1px solid $background__color--secondary;
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            background: $background__color--secondary;
        }
        &:after {
            @include icon($bars-icon);
            @include layout($margin: 0 0 0 6px)
        }
    }
    .navbar__brand {
        @include text($size: $text__size--md, $color: $text__color--white, $line: 28px, $weight: bold);
        &:hover,
        &:active,
        &:focus {
            color: $text__color--white;
        }
    }
    .navbar__collapsingNav li.active a {
        color: $background__color--white;
        background: $background__color--secondary;
        &:hover,
        &:active,
        &:focus {
            color: $background__color--white;
            background: $background__color--secondary;
        }
    }
    .navbar__collapsingNav .navbar__item {
        @include text($size: $text__size--sm, $color: $text__color--white, $weight: bold);
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            color: $text__color__secondary--light;
        }
    }
}


/* HEADER */

.header {
    background-image: url('../../../assets/img/header-background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    @include layout($padding: $padding--big 0 90px 0);
    .header__profileimage {
        @include img(300px,
        300px,
        $radius: 50%, $shadow: 2px 2px 8px 2px gray);
        @include layout($margin: 10px auto 0 auto);
    }
    .header__textbox--title {
        @include text($size: $text__size--xbig, $color: $text__color--white, $weight: bold);
    }
    .header__textbox--subtitle {
        @include text($size: $text__size--lowmd, $color: $text__color--white, $line: 50%, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($padding: 0 0 $padding--big 0);
    }
}


/* SECTIONS */

.section1 {
    background-color: $background__color--white;
    @include layout($padding: $padding--sm auto $padding--big auto);
    .section1__title {
        @include text($size: $text__size--big, $color: $text__color--base, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--big);
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .section1__image,
    .section1__image--last {
        text-align: center;
        @include img(250px,
        300px,
        5px);
        @include layout($margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px);
    }
    .section1__image--last {
        @include layout($margin: 20px 20px 100px 20px);
    }
}

.section2 {
    background-color: $background__color--secondary;
    @include layout($padding: $padding--sm 0 $padding--sm 0, $minheight: 500px);
    .section2__title {
        @include text($size: $text__size--big, $color: $text__color--white, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--big);
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .section2__text {
        @include text($size: $text__size--base, $color: $text__color--white, $align: justify);
    }
}

.section3 {
    background-color: $background__color--white;
    @include layout($padding: $padding--sm 0 $padding--big 0);
    .section3__title {
        @include text($size: $text__size--big, $color: $text__color--base, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--big 0 $padding--sm 0);
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .section3__form--input {
        @include text($size: $text__size--base, $color: $text__color--base, $align: left);
    }
    .section3__button {
        @include text($size: $text__size--base, $color: $text__color--white, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($margin: 0 0 80px 0);
    }
}


/* FOOTER */

.footer .footer--above {
    background-color: $background__color--footer--above;
    .footer--above__title {
        @include text($size: $text__size--md, $color: $text__color--white, $weight: bold);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--sm 0 20px 0);
        transform: uppercase;
    }
    .footer--above__text {
        @include text($size: $text__size--base, $color: $text__color--white);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--xsm 0 $padding--big 0);
    }
    .footer--above__map {
        @include img(200px,
        350px);
        @include layout($padding: $padding--xsm 0 $padding--xsm 0);
    }
    .footer--above__list {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        .footer--above__btnicon {
            @include layout();
            @include img(50px,
            50px,
            $border: 2px solid $background__color--white, $radius: 100%, $shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px $background__color--navbar, $display: inline-block);
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            &:focus,
            &:hover,
            &:active {
                background: red;
            }
            .footer--above__btnicon--fb:after {
                @include icon($facebook-icon);
            }
            .footer--above__btnicon--tw:after {
                @include icon($twitter-icon);
            }
            .footer--above__btnicon--lkin:after {
                @include icon($linkedin-icon);
            }
            .footer--above__btnicon--ghub:after {
                @include icon($github-icon);
            }
        }
    }
}

.footer--below {
    background: $background__color--navbar;
    .footer--below__text {
        @include text($size: $text__size--xsm, $color: $text__color--white);
        @include layout($padding: 14px);
    }
}


/* MEDIA */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .header {
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
    section {
        padding: 75px 0;
    }
    section.first {
        padding-top: 75px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 25px 0;
        -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: padding 0.3s;
        transition: padding 0.3s;
        .navbar__brand {
            font-size: 2em;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
    }
    .navbar.affix {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    .navbar.affix .navbar__brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    .header {
        padding-top: 200px;
        padding-bottom: $padding--xbig;
        .header__textbox--title {
            font-size: 4.75em;
        }
        .header__textbox--subtitle {
            font-size: 1.75em;
        }
    }
    .section1 .section1__item {
        margin: 0 0 30px;
    }
}
```

Full project live: https://evandcp.github.io/MyWebsite/

Comment: Can't anyone take a look and help me out please? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only a little familiar with SASS because I work with LESS most of the time, so I'll focus on your markup to get the ball rolling.

#### Markup

**Outline**

Keep in mind, that in HTML5 sectioning elements can start with a `h1`-element as well.

However, try to create a hierarchic structure. This means, that a `h1`-element directly followed by a `h4`-element doesn't make much sense. Especially when you start to use `h2` afterwards for other content:

```
<h1 class="header__textbox--title">EVAN SURNAME</h1>
<h4 class="header__textbox--subtitle">Web Developer</h4>
<!-- […] -->
<h2 class="section1__title">Portfolio</h2>
```

Also, this looks like a subheading where w3.org says:

> `h1`–`h6` elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection.

<sup>From w3.org [4.12.1 Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-idioms.html#sub-head)</sup>

The linked specification suggests different approaches to handle the problem. One possibility is this:

```
<h1>
    EVAN SURNAME
    <span>Web Developer</span>
</h1>
```

**Links without any text**

You have some links like this:

```
<a href="#page--top"></a>
<a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--fb"></span></a>
```

Of course, most people will see the icon and understand the link's meaning. But visitors using a screenreader or search bots don't have a clue, what the link is about. Simply spend them a `title`-attribute:

```
<a href="#page--top" title="Scroll back to top"></a>
<a href="#" class="footer--above__btnicon" title="Follow me on Facebook"><span class="footer--above__btnicon--fb"></span></a>
```

Some goes for the project listing.

**Empty `p`-elements**

In your form you have empty elements:

```
<p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
```

I think you'll fill these, if an error for the input occurs. I would say, insert these elements when they are really needed and remove the empty paragraphs in the beginning.

#### Live Page

A few things I've noticed in the *live demo*:

- There's an error in the console, because the file `favicon.ico` is missing.
- It's recommended that `<meta charset="UTF-8">` is the first child of the `head`-element. You can see it in all examples on w3.org. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573544/1456376) to ["*In <head>, which comes first: <meta> or <title>?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5572471/1456376) has some more insights:

> […] if your title came before that, it has already been interpreted as ASCII, which could be wrong, depending on what was in the title.

- You include `font-awesome.css` and `font-awesome.min.css`, which seems redundant.

#### Appearance of the Live Page

A few more things on the *live demo* regarding the design*:

- The header's blue background image doesn't fill the container for screen sizes over ~1200px width.
- The header seems broken on mobile. Only on a few screen widths name and subtitle are visible. Sometimes the image is larger than the blue background.
- In the mobile view the projects are aligned left. It might look better, if they are centered as the rest of the page as well.
- There's a white area below the red footer.
- It seems that one or multiple containers/elements are wider than the screen. You can always scroll horizontal a few pixels.

<sup><sup>*</sup> Seen in Safari 9.1 on macOS.</sup>

Comment: Wow thank you for all your suggestions and helpful corrections!! Will work on everything you said thanks!!